# IntelliJ IDEA Gradle sync: Problem with setting Gradle's Java home to some JDKs

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have no problem with:

1. `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/openjdk1.8.0_202`

in my (global) `gradle.properties` file. Also, no problem without it (with nothing set). But if replace it with one of below configurations (all paths are valid):

2. `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/openjdk-9.0.4`
3. `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/openjdk-10.0.1`
4. `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/openjdk-11.0.1`
5. `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\oraclejdk-11.0.1`

then I will get an error message (same for each) after I save the file and *import Gradle changes* in **IntelliJ IDEA**:

> Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
>   Error: Could not find or load main class java.base.java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.base.java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

---

The note is the issue is only for *IDE Gradle sync*. Gradle tasks themselves work correctly (independent from IDE)! Even when I run `gradle --status` (see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status) about it) can see everything is OK and daemon is running using JDK 11:

```
>gradlew --status
   PID STATUS   INFO
 10668 IDLE     5.0
```

And the path of `PID: 10668`:

```
>wmic process where "processId=10668" get Name, ProcessID, ExecutablePath
ExecutablePath                                     Name      ProcessId
C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe  java.exe  10668
```

Comment: Few doubts - Is that a plugin that you're talking about here?  - Did you update any configurations other than your `.gradle` update as mentioned in the question.  Few other checks 1. IntelliJ up to date? 2. `main class java.base.java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`, I believe you've specified either `exports` or `opens` which is what is not recognized. Maybe clearing the doubts would help know where exactly the issue is. Make sure to use compatible versions and update the question with details. On other hand, try using `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Xmx1024m` instead of `MaxPermSize`

Comment: @nullpointer - Thanks. After hours of researches for replying your questions, I found the answer! The problem was from my IDE configuration. I realized If I have a fresh installation of IntelliJ IDEA or just removing [its configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) then the problem will be solved. After a lot of *exporting*-and-*importing* my old settings, I found out the issue was from **SDK Table**.

Comment: Keep trying out things. (thumbs up), go ahead and answer the question with details if that could help someone in the future.

Comment: @nullpointer - But I don't know why correcting them from `Project Structure` (or `Structure for new Projects` in `Other Settings`) couldn't solve the issue. Finally, I *imported* it (and only it) from a fresh installation.

Comment: @nullpointer. OK, I will post an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found out the issue was from my IDE settings. It was from **SDK Table**.

I don't know why correcting them from `Project Structure` (or `Structure for new Projects` in `Other Settings`) couldn't solve the issue. Finally, I *imported* it (and only it) from a fresh installation.

---

Note: You don't need a fresh installation really. Just enough to close your IDE, rename [its configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and re-open it.

Then IDE starts freshly. This is an opportunity for the test. If OK export pointed setting ... <kbd>File</kbd> `->` <kbd>Export Settings ...</kbd>:

[image]

to a file. Then return to your previous state and import the exported file:

[image]

If the issue reverted you need to check other settings (other than *SDK Table*).

Comment: In my case SDK import/export did not help really, however just removing gradle.properties file from the .gradle folder in the user home solved the initial error. Really weird bug... Many thanks for posting this!

Comment: @Dime. You're welcome. Doesn't removing *gradle.properties* cause removing `org.gradle.java.home`? If so the issue has been cleared. If not, I suggest posting the solution as an answer. It may help others.

Comment: Yes, when gradle.properties is gone, gradle.java.home property is also no longer set. But, as there are other ways of setting gradle.java.home, it is acceptable in my setup. Still wondering why this properties affects IntelliJ Gradle integration in such a weird way :) My initial question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221693/gradle-5-and-intellij-2018-3-unrecognized-option-add-opens-or-java-base-java

Comment: @Dime. Is the problem still there after a fresh installation of IntelliJ IDEA? I. e. after removing (moving) [its configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)? I want to know the issue is from the application itself or from its data ...

Comment: Yes. In my case, re-installation of IntelliJ or empty configuration folders did not help at all. Also re-import of fresh SDK Tables, as you have suggested. No idea why. As soon as gradle.properties is back, the build in IntelliJ does not work anymore. And it does not work only in IntelliJ and only in case of Java 11 and Gradle 5.x (specified in the wrapper). Gradle 4.x works just fine with Java 11 and IntelliJ...

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili - I too had the exact same issue. I was initially using JDK 8 with gradle and then decided to upgrade to JDK 9. That is when my issue started. Tried many things, but nothing would work. That is when I gave up on the issue and moved to using Eclipse. 4 months passed after which I found this question and answer. Now I am back to using IntelliJ. Thanks.

Comment: @RahulKhimasia - I am happy that I could help you.