# Gradle 5 and IntelliJ 2018.3. Unrecognized option: --add-opens or java.base.java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I have a complex set of projects built by Gradle 4.10.3. I can build them from the command line, but I can also import them to IntelliJ 2018.3 Ultimate without major issues.

When I upgrade my Gradle to 5.1.1, the projects are still building fine from the console, however I can no longer import (or refresh) the project in IntelliJ :(

The configuration part goes fine, but the daemon process could not be started within IntelliJ. If I set Gradle JVM to Java 8 in the IntelliJ project settings, I get an error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
```

If I set Gradle JVM to Java 11 in the IntelliJ project settings, I get a different error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java.base.java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.base.java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

As soon as I execute `gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.10.3` (change back the wrapper to 4.10.3), the IntelliJ plugin works fine again.

If I add gradle idea task (idea gradle plugin) to the scripts, it executes fine from the console also with the version 5.1.1.

Removing .idea settings from the user folder did not help. Clean import did not help either. All possible settings inside IntelliJ related to Gradle (including all wrapper-related settings) are tried. Nothing helped :(

The problem seems to be so trivial, however I cannot find a solution since few days :( Where those `--add-opens` are coming from? How to prevent this?

Comment: What JDK do you run IDE under (can be seen in "About" dialog)?

Comment: The native JDK co-deployed with IntelliJ. I did try also to use JRE 11. The IntelliJ has started, but the problem was exactly the same. I've just posted below the only solution that did help me so far! I hope it can be useful also someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause was the `gradle.properties` file in the `.gradle` folder in the user home. Just removing the file solves this problem with IntelliJ.

Still it would be nice to know the cause of this...

Very weird bug!

Credits:
[IntelliJ IDEA Gradle sync: Problem with setting Gradle's Java home to some JDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989697/intellij-idea-gradle-sync-problem-with-setting-gradles-java-home-to-some-jdks)

Comment: This is a wonderful case! Can you show your `gradle.properties` file? Which part of the file causing the error? Just if it exists? Or a special part in the file?

Comment: This was just one-liner pointing to a specific JDK version. In my case: `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.1`. Most probably it would be enough to only remove `org.gradle.java.home` from the file, but I did not test this.

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur, when you have two versions of JVM's has installed, while switching one to another version we might get this error.

Solution(IntelliJ IDE):
Click on your project -> open module settings -> go to project settings -> project language level -> change to 8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.

once it has changed, rebuild your application.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to point the IDE to your own JAVA_HOME instead of the one included in the IDE (Android Studio, though, so YMMV).